# Search bar alignment in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

The issue is search button is coming in the next line instead pf side to input ,this is only in ie7 ,works fine in all browsers
     #search-form {
    background: #e1e1e1; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */
    width: 365px;

```
/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear,left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(243,243,243)), color-stop(1, rgb(225,225,225)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(243,243,243) 0%, rgb(225,225,225) 100%);

/* Rounded Corners */
border-radius: 17px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-radius: 17px;

/* Shadows */
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

/*** TEXT BOX ***/
input[type="text"]{
background: #fafafa; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(250,250,250)), color-stop(1, rgb(230,230,230)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(250,250,250) 0%, rgb(230,230,230) 100%);

border: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.8);
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px;
padding: 5px;
width: 250px;

/* Rounded Corners */
border-radius: 17px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-radius: 17px;

/* Shadows */
box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

/*** USER IS FOCUSED ON TEXT BOX ***/
input[type="text"]:focus{
outline: none;
background: #fff; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(255,255,255)), color-stop(1, rgb(235,235,235)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(255,255,255) 0%, rgb(235,235,235)  100%);
}

/*** SEARCH BUTTON ***/
input[type="submit"]{
background: #44921f;/* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(79,188,32)), color-stop(0.15, rgb(73,157,34)), color-stop(0.88, rgb(62,135,28)), color-stop(1, rgb(49,114,21)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(79,188,32) 0%, rgb(73,157,34) 15%, rgb(62,135,28) 88%, rgb(49,114,21) 100%);

border: 0;
color: #eee;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
font: 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
height: 30px;
margin: 4px 4px 0;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
width: 84px;
outline: none;

/* Rounded Corners */
border-radius: 30px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;

/* Shadows */
box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
/*** SEARCH BUTTON HOVER ***/
input[type="submit"]:hover {
background: #4ea923; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgb(89,222,27)), color-stop(0.15, rgb(83,179,38)), color-stop(0.8, rgb(66,143,27)), color-stop(1, rgb(54,120,22)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(89,222,27) 0%, rgb(83,179,38) 15%, rgb(66,143,27) 80%, rgb(54,120,22) 100%);
}
input[type="submit"]:active {
background: #4ea923; /* Fallback color for non-css3 browsers */

/* Gradients */
background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(89,222,27)), color-stop(0.15, rgb(83,179,38)), color-stop(0.8, rgb(66,143,27)), color-stop(1, rgb(54,120,22)));
background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(89,222,27) 0%, rgb(83,179,38) 15%, rgb(66,143,27) 80%, rgb(54,120,22) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the div in which input submit and input text are is probably too small (width) for ie7, so use different stylesheet for ie7 and define different attributes for the width for ie7. You posted only css for input boxes but I guess. Anyway, try to put float left or right also for input[type="text"] and give both, submit and text input, **display: block;** And define their width and height, maybe also line-height for ie7 in px.